# Clearcase merge by different user

Tags: clearcase

A subbranch is created from 'A' let's call it 'B'.

User 'UA' would be working on 'A' and User 'UB' would be working on 'B'.

How can we merge 'B' on to 'A' and still maintain the changes to be owned by 'B'?

When a merge is required 'UA' sets in to 'A' view and performs a checkout and does a merge (cleartool merge), and checks-in. By doing so all the contributions by 'UB' on branch 'B' are now present in branch 'A'. But when we use annotate sub command, 'UB' is not shown as contributor.

Answer (score 0):

> But when we use annotate sub command, 'UB' is not shown as contributor

One possible solution would be make sure to use a view owned by UB with the same config spec as the UA view.
And use the UB view to make the merge of the branch `B` on to `A`.

Comment: With current setup, both the views have same config spec, Can you eloborate on "And use the UB view to make the merge of the branch B on to A"

Comment: @Naks I mean: make sure that user B is making the merge, in order for annotate to reflect the fact that the merge has been created/contributed by user B.

Comment: I might have missed some details here. Issue is the merging will be done by the system after perform various checks that there are no issues with the code. I have thought of an option where the system does 'su' and run the commands on behalf of 'UB' but I was wondering if clearcase has some option to do this.